# getting wrong columns/rows format retrieving the columns and rows from a CSV File (OleDbConnection and DataTable))

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, registry, oledbconnection

I have a problem with a CSV File.

Im trying to get the columns and rows from a CSV File, but my Code(below) isn't getting the rows and columns in the right format.

Example for the [CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyVL6.jpg)

The Code I'm using now looks like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string FileName = strFilePath;

using (FileStream stream = File.Open(Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\mulus\Desktop", "schema.ini"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}]", FileName));
        writer.WriteLine("Format=Delimited(;)");
        writer.WriteLine("TextDelimiter=\"");
        writer.WriteLine("ColNameHeader=True");
    }
}
            
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection
       ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " +
         Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) +
         "; Extended Properties = \"Text;FMT=Delimited(;)\"");
conn.Open();

var abc = Path.GetFileName(FileName);

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(FileName), conn);
adapter.Fill(dt);

conn.Close();
```

I have tried multiple stuff:

- Tried different Formats on the FileStream class
- without using the FileStream class
- changed "; Extended Properties = "Text;FMT=Delimited(;)"");" to Format=Delimited(;), FMT=TabDelimiter and Format=TabDelimiter (it just ignores it)
- Tried to change it in the Registry itself, but there came this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1phx.jpg) (Cannot edit: error writing the value's new conents)
- I also tried to give me "Full Control", but I don't have enough rights to do this

But I also tried to do this with a different code, but this one ignores the ";" symbol in the B Column ("45;43") and sees it as 2 Columns instead of 1 and overall the formatting is really messed:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath, Encoding.Default))
{
    string[] headers = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (string header in headers)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(header);
    }
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = rows[i];
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

}
```

Also it looks like using this code for a CSV file is error-prone and not a good idea at all.

If you have an idea for the mistake or another idea how to do this, I would really appreciate it.

System: Winodws 7, Excel 2010,

Comment: have you checked the file you  linked as an example ? Is it CSV File ?

Answer (score -1):

Use the CsvHelper package https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/
Both the JET engine and your own homecooked solution can't beat what CsvHelper can do for you out of the box.

Using this MCVE based on your screenshots:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("A;B;C;D;E;");
sb.AppendLine("1;\"45;43\";\"-A\n-B\n-C\";tomato;potato;");
sb.AppendLine("2;\"55;34\";\"-D\n-E\n-F\";carrot;parrot;");

var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration{ Delimiter =";"};
using (var reader = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
    var cnt =1;
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Row>();
    foreach(var rec in records)
    {     
       cnt++.Dump("record");
       rec.A.Dump("A");
       rec.B.Dump("B");
       rec.C.Dump("C");
       rec.D.Dump("D");
       rec.E.Dump("E");
    }
}
```

I get this output:

[image]

And I used this DTO class:

```
class Row
{
   public string A {get;set;}
   public string B {get;set;}
   public string C {get;set;}
   public string D {get;set;}
   public string E {get;set;}
    
};
```

For the record: The JET engine will never read that example CSV file for you in a meaningful way. It is not build to deal with line-breaks inside text fields.